# Opening suspicious files

Tags: malware

How can I deal/inspect a suspicious file on my mac short of installing and creating a full blown virtual machine instance? On windows when I want to open a suspicious file I use the sandboxing app [sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/) Is there something comparable/safe on mac?

Comment: what is a suspicious file?

Comment: In my case, a zip file containing several files, one of which is a .app file.

Comment: You can explore the app contents without executing it bay right clicking on it and selecting "Show package contents".

Comment: @user79950 Try my suggestions. Just open up terminal and enter the commands.

Answer (score 1):

Open up the terminal and try:

```
zipinfo zipFileOfInterest.zip
```

If you really want some "verbose" information output, then enter:

```
zipinfo -v zipFileOfInterest.zip
```

The "-v" option will output a bit more information :)

Also, try `man zipinfo` to get the rundown of what options/etc is available.

You can also try:

```
unzip -l zipFileOfInterest.zip
```

These will allow you to peak inside the .zip without extracting what is inside.